# Downloading Maven Dependency with Maven Version in the file name

Tags: maven-3

I am trying to download an artifact from Maven and I have to have the version with the timestamp from Nexus and I keep getting the SNAPSHOT version.

```
mvn -U org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:copy -Dartifact=my:module:1.0-SNAPSHOT -DoutputDirectory=./tmp -Dmdep.stripVersion=false -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=false
```

Does anyone know how to download a version that has the timestamp in it?
Ex.    1.0-20180314.#####-.jar

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete everything out of my local repository then I had to update with a couple more parameters

```
mvn -U org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:copy -Dartifact=my:module:1.0-SNAPSHOT:<packaging>:<classifier> -DoutputDirectory=./tmp -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=false -DoutputAbsoluteArtifactFilename=true -Dmdep.stripVersion=false
```

After that, everything worked appropriately.